# autocomplete search inputtext box data not geting

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, codeigniter

I want to type some key in the input box and show related data but I am keypress but not show any data. I am using **Codeigniter  and javascript**  share code please help me

**javascript**

```
 $("#segment").autocomplete({
    minLength: 1,
    source: function(req, add){
        $.ajax({
            url: '<?php echo base_url() ?>get_autocomplete',
            dataType: 'json',
            type: 'POST',
            data: req,
            success: function(data){
                if(data.response =='true'){
                   add(data.message);
                }
            }
        });
    }
});
```

**view page**

```
    <div class="container">
       <label for="segment">Segment</label>
       <input type="text" name="segment" value="" id="segment" />
   </div>
```

**controllers**

```
public function get_autocomplete(){

$db2 = $this->load->database('dpr',TRUE); 
$keyword = $this->input->post('term');
$data['response'] = 'false'; 
$query  = $this->doctor_health_model->get_autocomplete($keyword);
if($query->num_rows() > 0){
   $data['response'] = 'true'; 
   $data['message'] = array(); 
   foreach($query->result() as $row){
      $data['message'][] = array('label'=> $row->medicine_name, 'value'=> $row->medicine_name); 
   }
}
echo json_encode($data);
}
```

**json data**

```
{"response":"true","message":[{"label":"CAP TOPP D ","value":"CAP TOPP D "},{"label":"TAB FOLIC ACID 5","value":"TAB FOLIC ACID 5"},{"label":"TAB MTX 12.5","value":"TAB MTX 12.5"},{"label":"TAB PICSUL","value":"TAB PICSUL"},{"label":"TAB RELANAC PLUS","value":"TAB RELANAC PLUS"},{"label":"TAB SAAZ 1 GM","value":"TAB SAAZ 1 GM"},{"label":"TOPFENAC OIL","value":"TOPFENAC OIL"}]}
```

**Model**

```
public function get_autocomplete($keyword)
  
    {   $db2 = $this->load->database('dpr',TRUE);
        $db2->select('medicine_name');
        $db2->from('dpr_medicine');
        $db2->where('status', 0);
        $db2->like('medicine_name', $keyword);
        $db2->order_by("medicine_name", "asc");
        $query = $db2->get();
        return $query;
    }
```

Comment: I think you need to use ajax since your requesting from the db

Comment: yes sir but i have no idea where code is missing so please help me

Comment: hello can you any body help me sir ?